# Retornar valor de radio button

Tags: html, mysql

Apesar de ter definido o valor padrão do campo para "N" no MySQL, ao usar radio button no formulário, se este não estiver selecionado, o registro vem como nulo. Como fazer para que o registro inserido, no qual o radio button não esteja checado venha como "N"?

A configuração da tabela está assim:
[image: Modelagem dos dados]

E o registro, depois de inserido com o uso de radio button fica assim:
[image: Registro após utlização do formulário]

Estou usando a seguinte codificação:

```
<label for="b_ant">Base Anterior</label><input name="b_ant" type="radio" value="S" />
<label for="b_grade">Base na Grade</label><input name="b_grade" type="radio" value="S" />
```

Comment: No insert, coloque assim: `IFNULL(b_ant,DEFAULT(b_ant)`

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Francisco. Devo colocar isso via PHP ou direto no form?